# Seeking documentation for qgis.utils module?

Tags: qgis, plugins

There is a PyQGIS module called `utils` that I can't find any documentation for. It seems to have some useful functions for loaded plugins.

Within the Python console in QGIS you can run `qgis.utils.plugins` and a dictionary for each loaded plugin is returned.

```
dir(qgis.utils.plugins)
```

returns this list of attributes

```
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
```

And this returns the attributes of an instance of a plugin:

```
dir(qgis.utils.plugins.get('<plugin-name>'))
```

Seems like this could be useful for building unit tests or creating interactions between plugins.

However I cannot find any documentation about the `utils` module in the QGIS API Documentation. This description has been provided: [Difference between qgis.utils and qgis.core?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158947/difference-between-qgis-utils-and-qgis-core), but is there further documentation that describes the purpose of this module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you type `help(qgis.utils)` in the **Python Console**, it will print the associated functions within that module with a basic description for each.

I also cannot find documentation for it but you could check the `utils.py` file in the QGIS directory (mine is in `C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/qgis/`) to see how each of the associated function works.

Comment: Looks like this is the only other documentation at present. I had also found https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/utils.py which contains the doc strings shown by the `help()` command.